# Hi, please help I need Sepolia Eth and the faucets scams/down/refusing signup

Tags: ether

OK, I don't trust Google a lot on my system, and this is a personal preference related to persistent cookies that track my buying habits, and I like buying lots of stuff, so no to the data collectors.
I'm sorry that is why I am in this bind, and here we are I am trying to test a C based script for triangular arbitrage that I got from Github, and well its the usual the Youtube video with bad TOS, and banned, and then his page has no email, and really lots of stars but who knows? So here I am bored wanting to use my MetaMask to connect to the Sepolia testnet, well I am the standard crypto guy and just grab a burner computer so that no code is executed that would compromise my network, files, or other systems. So anywho, the faucets that ask you to connect your Metamask are a scam, not always but why risk it. If I can't give a destination address and receive coin without signing up with personal information, giving up personal emails, or being treated like a criminal for fantasy ETHEREUM, then I don't know, hence my nickname, HELP!